# extracting text fields surrounded by other formatting related text

Tags: java, regex

I have records that look like this

```
(%1) %2 <span style='color:darkgreen'><b>[%3]</b></span>
```

I would like to pick out the fields designated by %1, %2, and %3 using a regex in Java , but I cannot figure it out. Part of the difficulty is square and angled brackets may appear in the fields. Can someone please help me out... thanks!

Okay, just to clarify, the fields I want to extract do not actually start with the % symbol. So a record might look like this

```
(ABC) Hello World <span style='color:darkgreen'><b>[Some green text]</b></span>
```

So the text I want is

ABC
  Hello World
  Some green text

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just as an advice how to do it: try to build regexp which will extract from `(%1)` only, then extend it, so it will work with `(%1) %2`, and so on. Write a bit of unit tests for your regexps, if you not sure 100%.

Comment: are the %1, %2 literals or does a string represented by %1 actually start with a % sign ? If not, can you add some more real examples?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

As JavaScript does not support lookbehind,

```
(%\w+)\b
```

or

```
(%\S+)
```